# Repair/Uninstall Mesos after cleanup

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

The mesos server ran out of disk space and so we were doing a cleanup by removing some of the old docker containers. But now the marathon won't start and digging deeper shows nor does zookeeper. The docker log says that it cannot load some containers.

But what we noticed was that zookeeper get started then stops. So we had at look at the zookeeper folder and the the conf was missing. This was also removed on the other master server as well which we had not touched. I presume this is to do with the link between the masters. Now the slave has this conf folder but it has the default folder and files and I noticed that this is a symlink that points to the /etc/alternatives/zookeeper-conf folder.
Running the dockerfile to recreate the missing cointainer says:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container d13b8aa28d383a3ca54b39ce74f5a81d80030a2ad0dde52966293ced9ef26663: [8] System error: exec: "mesos-master": executable file not found in $PATH

It doesn't recognise the Restart command either.

Is there a quick way to repair this to get it working as it used to? I am using Mesos 0.23 on Ubuntu 14.04

How do I uninstall Mesos?

Any help is appreciated as I am fairly new to this and so only have a basic understanding of how all this works.

Answer (score 0):

re "how to uninstall Mesos", my way is

```
configure --prefix="your_install_path"
make
make uninstall
```